# "Failed to start load/save screen backlight brightness" after spontaneous restart

Tags: boot, manjaro, backlight

My PC is running Manjaro. Unfortunately since recently my PC is restarted by itself and is then displayed to me that.

```
[FAILED] Failed to start load/save screen backlight brightness of backlight:acpi_video0
```

Can someone please explain to me what this is and how I can fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

searching for the same error lead to [this thread](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/resolution-help-needed-systemd-backlight-backlight-acpi-video0-service-loaded-failed-failed/68131/9)

Editing the grub to add `acpi_backlight=video` fixed it for me.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_backlight=video"
```

Comment: could you please explain that to me as well? What is this acpi_backlight=video?